# How to extract the value of an async function that is to be sent as a response through a express route?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, routes

I am working on a program, that displays data of anime from MyAnimeList. I am using a module named **mal-scraper** to do so. You can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mal-scraper). It is an async module. I am using express and body-parser in the backend. So, here is the code:

```
const express = require("express"),
bp = require("body-parser"),
mal = require("mal-scraper"),
app = express()
app.use(bp.urlencoded({ extended: false })
// Home page (a form and a submission button for now)
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`<form action='/post' method='post'>
<input name='name' placeholder='Type...'>
<button type='submit'>Send</button>
</form>`)
})
// Post route
app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
 mal.getInfoFromName(req.body.name).then(data => {
   res.send(`<pre>
Anime Full Name: ${data[0].title}
<img src='${data[0].picture}'>
<p>${data[0].synopsis}</p>`)
}).catch(err => {
   res.send(err)
})
})
app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Running"))
```

So, the mal-scraper code runs well when I tested it without express i.e. gave an input and extracted the output only. But when, I integrated it with express, it always returned an empty object. The reason, mal-scraper was async. So, is there any way to get it working. I am new to async programming, so I need help in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request is sending back the error, which is an object. if you logg your error from the catch block you will see 'property title  does not exist on data'.

The data you are trying to display is not in an array, but an object and can be accest directly on data.

try this:

```
const express = require("express"),
bp = require("body-parser"),
mal = require("mal-scraper"),
app = express()
app.use(bp.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
// Home page (a form and a submission button for now)
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send(`<form action='/post' method='post'>
<input name='name' placeholder='Type...'>
<button type='submit'>Send</button>
</form>`)
})
// Post route
app.post('/post', (req, res) => {
 mal.getInfoFromName(req.body.name).then(data => {
   res.send(`<pre>
Anime Full Name: ${data.title}
<img src='${data.picture}'>
<p>${data.synopsis}</p>`)
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
   res.status(500).send({message: 'Something went wrong, please try again later', statusCode: 500});
})
})
app.listen(8080, () => console.log("Running"))
```

EDIT: I removed `[0]` from data[0].(property) which fixed your bug.

Also instead of sending back the full error directly, send a generic server error like `res.status(500).send({message: 'Something went wrong, please try again later', statusCode: 500})`

Another tip, learn async await. Makes it much easier to read the code :)